# How can I load an image referred to in a blob: URL into C#

Tags: c#, image, blob, webrequest, webresponse

I am trying to handle the dragging and dropping of an image in C# onto a WPF window.  I can extract the URL but sometimes it starts

https://

and sometimes

blob:https%3A//

The https:// works fine but blob: does not - code to load in c# below.  If I look at the content of the stream after removing blob: and converting https%3A to https:// as a string then it contains the default web page of the provider so I am not understanding how to use the blob: tag from c#

```
oWebRequest = System.Net.WebRequest.Create(sImageAddress);
WebResponse = oWebRequest.GetResponse();
oStream = oWebResponse.GetResponseStream();
oImage = System.Drawing.Image.FromStream(oStream);
oStream.Close();
```

Comment: When you create a WebRequest, the address must be any valid address that you can even open in your browser. I guess blob:https:// is not a valid address. Where the sImageAddress is comming from?

Comment: blob:https:// is valid within Chrome but not IE.